# D3 custom text label axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to customize my x axis on a d3 chart; I want to add two labels, "left" and "right" at both ends of it.

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
var xlabels = ["Left", "Right"]
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(xScale)
            .tickValues(xScale.domain())    
            .orient("bottom")
            .ticks(2)
            .tickFormat(xlabels)
            ;
```

Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`axis.tickFormat` as the name implies defines the label for each of the ticks, if you want to add new labels at both ends you need to add them on your own:

Assuming that you have a reference to the root svg in the var `svg`

```
svg.append('text')
  .attr('text-anchor', 'start')
  .attr('y', function () {
    // y position of the left label
    // typically a value less than the height of the svg
  })
  .attr('x', function () {
    // x position of the left label
    // typically a value near to 0
  })
  .text('Left')

svg.append('text')
  .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
  .attr('y', function () {
    // y position of the right label
    // typically a value less than the height of the svg
  })
  .attr('x', function () {
    // x position of the right label
    // typically a value near the width of the svg
  })
  .text('Right')
```

Also have a look at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1166403, these lines define a label like the one you need:

```
svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", width - 6)
  .attr("y", height - 6)
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(values[0].symbol);
```